# Why can I have properties of varying types when the index is of type number, but not of type string for Index Signature Types

Tags: typescript

Per the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), the following will not work:

```
interface NumberDictionary {
  [index: string]: number;
  length: number; // ok
  name: string;
}
```

But if I changed the shape of `NumberDictionary` to:

```
interface RevisedNumberDictionary {
  [index: number]: number;
  length: number;
  name: string;
  x: boolean;
  y: { a: string; b: number },
  z: () => void;
}
```

I understand that w/ `RevisedNumberDictionary` I won't be able to define an object, of type `RevisedNumberDictionary`, that has a property outside of `'length' | 'name' | 'x' | 'y' | 'z'` and numeric values, but don't get why it won't work when the index type is `string`.

Comment: Because length and name are string, not number, properties. `x[123 /* or any number */]` doesn't overlap with `x["foo" /* or any string */]`, but `x["length"]` does.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to connect the dots.